# Помогите разобраться с функцией i2c

Tags: c, указатели, avr

Давно уже в своих так сказать поделках  использую i2c (он же TWI).И не дает  мне покоя непонятный для меня кусочек реализации этого протокола.

```
void I2C_setCallbacks(void (*recv)(uint8_t), void (*req)());

inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) I2C_transmitByte(uint8_t data)
{
    TWDR = data;
}

static void (*I2C_recv)(uint8_t);
static void (*I2C_req)();

void I2C_setCallbacks(void (*recv)(uint8_t), void (*req)())
{
    I2C_recv = recv;
    I2C_req = req;
}

void I2C_requested()
{
    I2C_transmitByte(data_i2c);
}

void setup()
{
    // set received/requested callbacks
    I2C_setCallbacks(I2C_received, I2C_requested);

    // init I2C
    I2C_init(I2C_ADDR);
}
```

а именно функция I2C_setCallbacks() .  я конечно понимаю что она работает как то через указатели на функцию . Но охота понять именно как.
и как в этом обмене участвуют 
static void (*I2C_recv)(uint8_t); static void (*I2C_req)();

Comment: текста недостаточно чтобы понять, в данном фрагменте в I2C_setCallbacks просто двум указателям на функции присваиваются адреса функций и всё

Comment: тяжело разбираться с си после асма ) вроде  и знаешь  что делает программа а не понимаешь (

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри Евстифеев А. В. Микроконтроллеры AVR семейства Mega.Там описан протокол TWI и контроллер TWI. Лучше через регистры с ним работать. В книге описано как это делать, в том числе, и на C

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]